# What are the small things, look like stars, moving in the sky?

Tags: artificial-satellite

I have always been observing something that looks like a star but not as bright as a star moving from south to north at the same time every night.

What is it? It cannot be a star because I know stars do not move.

Comment: Uh...that could be anything. Airplanes?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by "stars don't movie".

Comment: Try this: http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03020/LightInTheSky_3020904c.jpg

Comment: Copy edited. Using standard grammar and checking spelling is more likely to attract quality answers.

Answer (score 4):

A starlike point visibly moving across the sky is a satellite. The biggest and brightest is the international space station, but there are many others.

They can be seen any night that is clear, usually shortly after dusk, or before dawn. http://www.heavens-above.com/ allows you to see predictions of when satellites will be overhead.

Comment: Say, is it true that you can (these days) see a satellite moving on any heading at all, from anywhere on Earth?  Or have we all generally agreed that satellites should only move in one sense, or that polar satellites should not precess - - - or something?  (Surprisingly I don't know this at all!)

Comment: The OP says there's "something that looks like a star but not as bright as a star moving from south to north at the same time every night". That's certainly not the ISS, and I'm skeptical that any other satellite would appear like that.

Comment: I agree its not the ISS. I think the OP has seen satellites at about the same time and jumped to a conclusion. Clearly "not as bright as a star" means nothing.